# Can't unzip with PHP?

Tags: php, unzip

I'm having trouble using PHP to unzip an uploaded file. I can upload fine, the .zip gets copied to where its supposed to, but it does not unzip. The directory and zip are being properly chmod'd to 777. The apache error logs just show "Error: Can't create [whateverfile]" for each file in the .zip. Any idea why this happens? Appreciate it! Please tell me if this belongs over at stackoverflow, but it seems to be an apache/os/somethingelse problem. Code follows:

```
<?php
$target_path = "/home/someuser/hostgames/";

mkdir($target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'],".zip") . "/",0777);
chmod($target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'],".zip") . "/",0777);


$target_path =$target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'],".zip") . "/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);



if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}


echo "<br/>Path is: $target_path<br/>";
echo "<br/>Command is: unzip $target_path<br/>";
shell_exec("chmod 777 $target_path");
shell_exec("unzip $target_path");


?>
```

Comment: chmodding anything to 777 can't be called proper

Comment: Here are a couple of comments on your code (they won't solve your problem, however). Move your first concatenation before the `mkdir` then you'll only need to do it once. Move your 'shell_exec' commands inside your `if` since there's no point in trying them if the file's not there. Oh, and like **rodjek** said, don't use 777.

Comment: Appreciate the input, this was just a quick and dirty script until I got it working. Things like 777 were just a test to see if there was any reason why the file was not being created due to permissions errors (the directory is obviously created by www-data, so it of course doesn't need 777- again, just testing). Again, thanks for the input, still totally baffled about this problem :[  (and it's not particularly easy to google for)

Comment: Most likely it fails cause "unzip $target_path" tries to extract the files into the dir where the php script is located, you need something along the lines of  "cd /home/someuser/hostgames/ ; unzip $target_path"

Comment: That was the problem, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code. I think this code is help you....
Note : ZipArchive class support PHP 5 >= 5.2.0 version. Please check your php version.
Make one extracthere folder in your root folder.

```
    $path = 'New folder.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$f = 0;
    if ($zip->open($path) === true) 
    {                    
        for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) 
        {                  
            if($zip->extractTo('extracthere/', array($zip->getNameIndex($i))))
            {
                $f = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                $f = 0; 
            }                
        }  
        $zip->close();                   
    }
    if($f==0)
    {
        echo 'Prolem';  
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Done';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution using the terminal SH command to execute 2 script commands in one line

```
 exec( "sh -c \"cd " . $path . " && unzip " . $path  . $filename . " -d " . $folder . "\"" );
```

which generates something along the line of :

```
sh -c "cd /var/www/project-X/wp-content/uploads/raw/ && unzip /var/www/project-x/wp-content/uploads/raw/filename.zip -d folderName"
```

This works perfectly for me